# Running functions defined within classes

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a python class which houses some info. I have another file which some of these functions refer to. My `get_date` , is working fine however, none of my other functions seem to be working. I am getting the error `AttributeError: PVData instance has no attribute 'time'` when calling the time function.

```
class PVData:
    def __init__(self):
        self.date = yesterday()
        self.data = load_data(self.date)

    def change_date(self, date):
        if self.date != date:
            self.date = date
          ##  self.refresh()
        else:
            self.date = date
            self.date = load_data(self.date)

        #time, temp, sun
        self.time = []
        self.temperature = []
        self.sunlight = []

        for minute in self.date:
            self.time.append(minute[0])
            self.temperature.append(minute[1])
            self.sunlight.append(minute[2])

        #power
        self.dictonary[a] = []

        for a in ARRAYS:
            self.dictionary[ARRAYS[i]].append(power)

    def get_date(self):
        return self.date

    def get_time(self, time_index):
        return self.time[time_index]

    def get_temperature(self):
        return self.temperature

    def get_sunlight(self):
        return self.sunlight

    def get_power(self, array):
        return self.dictionary[array]

pvd = PVData()
```

The load_data function is (in another file):

```
def load_data(dateStr):
    text = get_data_for_date(dateStr)
    data = []

    for line in text.splitlines():
        time, temp, sun, powerStr = line.split(',', 3)

        power = []
        for p in powerStr.split(','):
            power.append(int(p))

        data.append((time, float(temp), float(sun), tuple(power)))

    return data
```

which returns something such as:

```
[('19:00', 20.0, 0.0, (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 21, 31, 52)), (tuple 2), etc etc]
```

The error seems to be resulting because time is not a valid parameter for self, but I thought that was defined where `self.time = []`.
Excuse my lack of knowledge, python is quite new to me. Any ideas of why this is not doing as required?

Comment: self.time exists if change_date is called. Otherwise, it is not defined. Put it in the constructor (__init__) maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `time` as well as other variables that should be accessible from outside to `def init(self)`. Please keep in mind, that python creates variables in runtime, so if you want variable has been accessible in any place - they should be created on class initialization.

Added:
From your code it looks like, you should move `temperature` and `sunlight` to `def init(self)` as well.